# How to count the name if the grade is 80 or higher

Tags: excel, count, countif

[image]

I want to count how many times each student has earned a grade of 80 or higher. In the image, the highlighted in yellow part is what I want. I did that manually, but is there any formula that would do it?

Answer (score 1):

You want `Countifs()`.

In F2, next to "Adam", put `=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$11,E2,$C$2:$C$11,">=80")`

and drag down